# A term to describe how the media represents the people, things and events of our world

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I try to find the precise English term used in social science (medial studies) which describes how the media represents the people, things and events of our world. Is "the medial picture" the appropriate term?

Just for example: In my article I would like to provide the media picture/view of immigrants presented in our commercial televisions.

Comment: More context would be helpful. BTW, New Oxford American Dictionary defines "medial" as "situated in the middle", not as "related to media." - Maybe "the media view" is the term you are looking for - the view that the media has of the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *media* is commonly used as a noun adjunct when referring to the communications media (eg. the academic discipline is commonly called *media studies*).

I think the term you are looking for is *media representation*.